# unpaid fine implications in Netherlands

Tags: netherlands

I have a fine from 2014 from the Netherlands, where I was fined for cycling on the sidewalk.

I didn't pay the fine and some months later I left the country. My flatmate at the time said collectors from a collection company kept sending mail and even showed up on our door looking for me, however he informed them I had left the country.

Now, however, I might be going back there for work. Is there any chance this will catch up with me? What should I do?

Comment: The normal way to prevent problems due to an unpaid fine is to pay the fine. Any reason that is not the solution in this case?

Comment: This is not duplicate of [Going back to the Netherlands with outstanding fines?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/6044/going-back-to-the-netherlands-with-outstanding-fines) because that is another type of fine (not traffic)

Answer (score 1):

You can check [through here](https://business.gov.nl/regulation/fines/) *if* the fine is still registered and then pay it immediately. But if you can't find it via that page, I have no idea what to do.

The amount your were fined for [will have increased](https://www.cjib.nl/en/i-have-received-payment-reminder) ('reminder charges').

If your fine is still registered somewhere, you risk getting picked out a passport control, e.g. [at Schiphol airport](https://www.dutchnews.nl/news/2015/07/officials-collect-unpaid-taxes-and-fines-at-schiphol/). [KMar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Marechaussee) will check the registers of the Centraal Justitieel Incassobureau (CJIB) and you will have to pay on the spot.

There is a chance that on an intra-Schengen flight (if not connecting to/from an extra-Schengen flight!) that you won't be checked, but I would not risk it.